# Как из торрента получить ссылку на видео

Tags: php, torrent

Как из торрента получить ссылку на видео. Как это делает TS Magic

Comment: никак

Answer (score 3):

В .torrent нет никаких ссылок на видео, да и не может быть в принципе. TS Magic фактически сам работает как torrent-клиент, старается правильно выстраивать порядок запроса частей, и вместо сохранения - проигрывает их.

Comment: Есть ли известный алгоритм?

Comment: Формат torrent-файла и протокол описаны на bittorrent.org. Исходники для разбора легко находятся на phpclasses.org по запросу "torrent", как скачивать - любой клиент с открытыми исходниками.